# Android does not show subtitle and title

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I create  an `actionbar`, the `actionbar`'s subtitle and title, and also an xml file because i want to center the `actionbar` text. When I run my project, the text is centred but the subtitle and title do not show.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.show();

    actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.action);
    TextView search = (TextView) actionBar.getCustomView().findViewById(
            R.id.mytext);

    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM
            | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME);
    actionBar.setSubtitle("mytest");
    actionBar.setTitle("mytest");
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    // action with ID action_refresh was selected
    case R.id.action_refresh:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Refresh selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    // action with ID action_settings was selected
    case R.id.action_settings:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Settings selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

}

Can anyone see any problems with this code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add [ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE) to your call to `setDisplayOptions` if you want the title/subtitle to appear. Note that on most smaller devices (such as phones) do **not** have room foran icon, title, custom layout, and the overflow menu.

Comment: i added but nothink happened (please look this) actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM
    | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME |ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE );